# Can not compile usbmouse.c : too few arguments to function 'usb_maxpacket'

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, usb-hid

I am trying to modify and compile `usbmouse.c`

While compiling it is saying that the function `usb_maxpackets` requires 3 arguments but the code I copied from the torvald git is passing only 2 arguments to this function

the code can be found here:

`https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbmouse.c`

I am using `debian gnu/linux 10`with kernel version `4.19.94-ti-r42`

Comment: You will need to change the call to add the 3rd argument back in for compatibility with the 4.19 kernel: `maxp = usb_maxpacket(dev, pipe, usb_pipeout(pipe));`. The number of parameters of this function was reduced from 3 to 2 in the 5.19 kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of parameters of the `usb_maxpacket()` function was changed from 3 to 2 in Linux kernel 5.19 onwards.  The third parameter indicated the direction of the pipe, but that information was redundant because the direction can be derived from the other two parameters.

For compatibility with the 4.19 kernel, the new function call `maxp = usb_maxpacket(dev, pipe);` needs to be changed to `maxp = usb_maxpacket(dev, pipe, usb_pipeout(pipe));`. (`usb_pipeout(pipe)` is the pipe direction.)

To make the code compatible with old and new kernels, the code can be conditionally compiled according to the kernel version:

```
#include <linux/version.h>
```

```
    /* In the function */
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,19,0)
    maxp = usb_maxpacket(dev, pipe, usb_pipeout(pipe));
#else
    maxp = usb_maxpacket(dev, pipe);
#endif
```

Alternatively, some compatibility code could be added before the function that calls `usb_maxpacket`:

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
```

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,19,0)
#undef usb_maxpacket
static inline u16 kcompat_usb_maxpacket(struct usb_device *udev, int pipe)
{
    return usb_maxpacket(udev, pipe, usb_pipeout(pipe));
}
#define usb_maxpacket(udev, pipe) kcompat_usb_maxpacket(udev, pipe)
#endif
```

```
    /* In the function */
    maxp = usb_maxpacket(dev, pipe);
```